# Is it fine to have multiple objects of same page in Selenium test script?

Tags: selenium

I have following code in my test script

```
@Test

public void homePageNavigation()

{
     LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

     //login function returns the HomePage object
     HomePage homePage = loginPage.login(login, pass); 

     //navgateToProfilePage() function returns a ProfilePage object   
     ProfilePage profilePage = homePage.navgateToProfilePage(); 

     //navigateBackToHomePage() function returns HomePage object and
     //takes the user back to Home Page again
     HomePage homePageReturn=profilePage.navigateBackToHomePage(); 

}
```

Now in the above code, i have 2 objects of `HomePage` i.e `homePage` and `homePageReturn`. Is it fine to use any of them further in my script?

Thanks
Rajan

Comment: why can't your navigateBackToHomePage(); return the same object like "return this;"

Comment: navigateBackToHomePage() function is in the ProfilePage class.
If i write return this, that function will return the current object i.e. ProfilePage object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the Page object static in nature so that you can call any method without doing multiple init ()

You did

HomePage homePage
HomePage homePageReturn

If the HomePage is Static in nature you can simply call the method. But not sure how you implemented your code.